# Не отображается стили на сайте laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я создал сайт на фреймворке laravel. В локалном сервере все работало нормально, а когда загрузил сайт на удаленный сервер стили перестали работат. И картинка, которая хранится на папке public/assets/images, тоже не отображается.
Код с blade.php:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{URL::asset('/css/app.css')}}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::asset('/js/app.js')}}"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{URL::asset('/assets/images/favicon.png')}}" type="image/png">
```

Вот мой .htaccess на корневом каталоге файл:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Но в сайте путь к public/assets/images/favicon.png и public/css/app.css правильно отображается:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://u3466231.smrtp.ru/public/css/app.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://u3466231.smrtp.ru/public/js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://u3466231.smrtp.ru/public/assets/images/favicon.png" type="image/png">
```

Comment: `php artisan storage:link` писали на сервере?

Comment: @VladimirGonchar на моем сервере не поддерживается ssh соединение, поэтому не могу использовать командную строку

Comment: Тогда придётся создавать ссылку на папку `/storage/app/public/` в папке `/public/` вручную. Сейчас скорее всего у Вас скопировалась ссылка с Вашей локальной системы. Само собой, ссылки не работают. Есть вариант ещё запустить эту команду, например, из контроллера (через `Artisan::call()`).